# How to validate that the path of an uploaded file is not malformed

Tags: file-upload, next.js, formidable

I'm developing an application with next.js

I have an api endpoint that receives FormData in the request.
I'm using Formidable to get the files from the request.
Than, upload the file from its temporary path on the server to AWS S3.

My question is, how can i validate that the user didn't malformed the path of the file, and sending the request with a malicious path. For example, changing the path to "../../secretFile".
A regular path for example would be:

C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Local\Temp\upload_e69daadcd956ae15fc00551832d1be82

Comment: Prevent from the user to pass paths at all, there is no any sense in it.
And sometimes there is no good reason for the user to specify the filename.

Comment: @felixmosh there is no way to prevent such things in the client. A malicious user can send the request from python script for example.

Comment: I mean, can i trust that path that i get from formidable? the user can't affect the temp path  that i get from formidable on the server right?

Comment: No, you can't trust any input from user, doesn't matter where it comes from, if the data comes from users it can be malicious, therefore, the best way is not allow it at all.
Hard code the path in your code.

Comment: You don't understand the use case. The user uploads a file to the server. I'm posting the file using FormData. In the server, i'm extracting the file data with Formidable package. than, I'm uploading the file to AWS using the "path" property in the file object. So, my question is, i can assume that the user can't determine the path that comes from formidable, am i right?

Comment: Don't assume this. all params that are coming from client must be treated as dangerous.

Comment: So what is the best practice to validate this path property? I'm not the first that deals with this question i guess :)